# How to stop Git rebase from proceeding if there are untracked files

Tags: git-rebase

I am creating a new rebase recipe, and having issues because untracked files are carried over from one step to the next.

How can I make git rebase not proceed if there are untracked files? This seems unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I can modify my `exec` command to run this at the end:

```
git add -N $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)
```

But, ideally there is a git config setting, where anyone can opt into safer behavior.